# Why is the argument for the accumulated price process allowed to be negative in asian options?

Tags: black-scholes, asian-option

Consider an Asian call option on some underlying with price process $S$ which follows a geometric Brownian motion, and accumulated price process $Y$, where
$Y_t  = \int_{0}^{t}S_u du$. Let $v$ be the function so that the price of the Asian option at time $t$ is $v(t, S_t, Y_t)$.

In Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II*, it is stated that

> at least mathematically, there is no problem with allowing $y$ to be negative... In integrated form this formula is $$Y_T = y + \int_{t}^{T}S_u du$$ Even if $y$ is negative, this makes sense, and in this case we could still have $Y_T > 0$ or even $\frac{1}{T}Y_T - K >0$ if the call expires in the money.

Why is this the case? Since $S$ is always positive, isn't $Y$ also always positive, being the integral of a positive function along each sample path? What is the point of extending the domain of $v$ so that $y$ can take negative values when it clearly cannot?

Comment: Isnt't $y$ just some constant? A constant doesn't really affect anything.

Comment: Effectively, there are two definitions of $Y_t$ here. One is _only_ the integral, the other is the integral plus a constant. The integral itself cannot become negative, you are right. But the constant can be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Shreve motivates this because he needs standard boundary conditions for the PDE he is solving. He shows that $S_t=0$ is an absorbing boundary for $S_t$ and leads to $Y\equiv y$ on $[t,T]\,.$ Vice versa, he cannot show that $Y_t=0$ is an absorbing boundary but he can show that $Y_t=-\infty$ is one in the limit.